# Elements added to YouTube video page with JavaScript don't show up in dark theme

Tags: javascript, html, css, youtube

Using JavaScript in the Firefox and Chrome consoles, I'm trying to add an HTML Div element above the video on a YouTube "watch" page (URL for a single video) like this:

```js
var mydiv = document.createElement("div");
mydiv.innerHTML = "<p>This is a test.</p>";
document.getElementById("primary-inner").prepend(mydiv);
```

This works as expected using the default YouTube light theme (selectable in the menu in the upper right on desktop).  I generally use dark themes and need this to work either way.  This has to be some kind of CSS problem.

I can see the new Div and P elements in the "Inspector" tab, and they take up space above the video.  The problem is that the elements aren't visible in Firefox or Chrome.  Sometimes they are visible very briefly as they fade to black.  I've tried changing the text color and opacity CSS values, but it doesn't seem to have any effect.

Please advise!